# Using CSS to create 'tags' - Design issue in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a section on a page that contains 'tags'. I used the code below for styling, but in IE (on some of the tags) there is a small space between the arrow part and the square part. This is the case only applies to some of the tags in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vzn3yw8r/2/

IE is the only browser I am experiencing this issue with. I thought it might be border-spacing, but that does not seem to be the case after testing.

[image: Unwanted Space in Tag]

**CSS**

```
.tags{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    right:24px;
    bottom:-12px;
    list-style:none;
}
.tags li, .tags a{
    float:left;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.tags a{
    margin-left:20px;
    padding:0 10px 0 12px;
    background:#38958d;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:4px;    
    border-top-right-radius:4px;    
}
 .tags a:before{
    content:"";
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-12px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent #38958d transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:12px 12px 12px 0;      
}
 .tags a:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:0;
    float:left;
    width:4px;
    height:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:#d9eae8;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #004977;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #004977;
    box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #004977;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tags">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Green Lantern</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Green Lantern</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Green Lantern</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Green Lantern</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Green Lantern</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Green Lantern</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Green Lantern</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Im not sure f it changes anything, but probably try around with the `box-sizing:` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a another quirk of IE not consistently rendering the :before pseudo-element.

The only workaround I could find was to chance the "left" style of a:before from -12px to -11px and then add some rounding to the left top and bottom corners of the "a" element to make the jagged corner look a little better.

CSS

```
.tags{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    right:24px;
    bottom:-12px;
    list-style:none;
}
.tags li, .tags a{
    float:left;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.tags a{
    margin-left:20px;
    padding:0 10px 0 12px;
    background:#38958d;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:4px;    
    border-top-right-radius:4px;   
    border-top-left-radius:2px;  /* ===change here=== */
    border-bottom-left-radius:2px;  /* ===change here=== */
}
 .tags a:before{
    content:"";
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-11px; /* ===change here=== */
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent #38958d transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:12px 12px 12px 0;      
}
 .tags a:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:0;
    float:left;
    width:4px;
    height:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:#d9eae8;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #004977;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #004977;
    box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #004977;
}
```

Comment: Have you reported this issue to Microsoft? If not I will.

Comment: I have not reported the issue.. Thanks, I will try your suggested CSS!

Comment: I've seem something similar and fixed it by setting the border to none/0px width. Don't ask me why, but IE always seems to think every image I put on a page has a border around it...